# Error while adding key/value to Python Dict in nested loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a Json Structure as Follows:

```
 {
   "_id" : ObjectId("asdasda156121s"),
    "Hp" : {
    "bermud" : [ 
        {
            "abc" : {
                "gfh" : 1,
                "fgh" : 0.0,
                "xyz" : [ 
                    {
                        "kjl" : "0",
                        "bnv" : 0,
                    }
                ],
                "xvc" : "bv",
                "hgth" : "INnn",
                "sdf" : 0,
                }
            }
        },
       {
            "abc" : {
                "gfh" : 1,
                "fgh" : 0.0,
                "xyz" : [ 
                    {
                        "kjl" : "0",
                        "bnv" : 0,
                    }
                ],
                "xvc" : "bv",
                "hgth" : "INnn",
                "sdf" : 0,
                }
            }
        },
        ..
```

I am trying to parse this json and add a new value with key ['cat'] inside the object 'xyz',below is my py code.

```
data = []

for x in a:
    for y in x['Hp'].values():
        for z in y:
            for k in z['abc']['xyz']:
                for m in data:
                    det = m['response']
                    // Some processing with det whose output is stored in s 
                    k['cat'] = s
    print x
```

However when x is printed only the last value is being appended onto the whole dictionary, wheras there are different values for s. Its obvious that the 'cat' key is being overwritten everytime the loop rounds,but can't find a way to make it right.What mistake am I making?

Comment: What is the data type of `s`?

Comment: s = {'x' : 'y'}

Comment: If you want to keep all values one option is to make it a list: instead of `k['cat'] = s` you can use `k.setdefault('cat', []).append(s)`

Comment: You are most likely mutating `s` instead of reassigning it. Please post the rest of the code.

Comment: Why not use python3? Show all of your code please.